# Downloaded .exe is incomplete, C++ Winsock

Tags: c++, winsock

Alright so anyways when I first started I was actually downloading the actual filesize, but now its not. The reason I have more strings is so I can make a substring then cut out the HTML header (Then write all the information after)

Anyways! Can anyone that knows WINSOCK tell me what is the problem? I want to learn Winsock to learn the core of things, so please don't recommend another API or something. Thanks!

I know when people add the ofstream::write into their while loop they use the return of recv, so I added it all up and then put into my ofstream::write at the end because I figured it was the same. (I didn't put in there because as said, I wanted to cut out the HTML header)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#define BUFFER_LEN 4096

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    addrinfoW *ptr = nullptr, *result = nullptr, hints = { 0 };
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    std::ofstream test;

    try {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
            throw(1);
        }
        if (GetAddrInfoW(L"www.mydati.com", L"80", &hints, &result) != 0) {
            throw(2);
        }

        ptr = result;
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            throw(3);
        }

        if (connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
            throw(4);
        }

        std::string SendBuffer;
        SendBuffer = "GET //download/hss-win2/HSS-773.exe / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        SendBuffer += "Host: www.mydati.com\r\n\r\n";
        send(ConnectSocket, SendBuffer.c_str(), SendBuffer.length(), 0);

        int ReturnBytes = 0;
        int ReturnStuff = 0;
        std::string recvBufferTest, recvBufferTest2;
        char recvBuffer[BUFFER_LEN] = { 0 };

        test.open("HotSpotShield.txt", std::ofstream::binary);


        while (ReturnStuff = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0) > 0) {

            ReturnBytes = ReturnBytes + ReturnStuff;
            std::cout << recvBuffer;
            recvBufferTest = recvBuffer;
            recvBufferTest2.append(recvBufferTest);
        }

        int HeaderPosition = 0;
        HeaderPosition = recvBufferTest2.find("\r\n\r\n");
        recvBufferTest = recvBufferTest2.substr(HeaderPosition + 4, std::string::npos);

        test.write(&recvBufferTest[0], ReturnBytes);
        MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);



    }

    catch (int FailureCode) {
        switch (FailureCode) {

        case 1:{
            MessageBox(NULL, L"WSAStartup was unable to start.", L"Error: 1", MB_OK);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
            }

        case 2: {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"GetAddrInfo did not find match.", L"Error: 2", MB_OK);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        case 3: {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"ConnectionSocket is empty", L"Error: 3", MB_OK);
            FreeAddrInfoW(result);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        case 4: {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"You are unable to connect", L"Error: 4", MB_OK);
            FreeAddrInfoW(result);
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this site you ask for solutions for your problem, not people trying to identify it for you and also solving it. Flagging as off topic.

Comment: Did you mean `while ((ReturnStuff = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0)) > 0)`

Comment: I am not trying to be a dick, but your question (if there is one) is not clear. You're supposed to ask for specific problems and include what have you tried. In your case, you're pasting your code and saying "tell me what's wrong". I mean... do you, at least, have a debug log? An output, something? What are we searching? The **fix-it-for-me** doesn't belong here, but rather a **i have a problem here, i tried this but it didn't work as supossed. It should do this ... but instead did this...**, etcetera...

Comment: @TrevinCorkery _"... for almost an hour ..."_ That's a ridiculously short time, until you need to ask at Stack Overflow. I'd accept 2-3 days of hard research before you might come here.

Comment: @Alejandro Iván Alright sorry, I have just seen a lot of people on here with shit attitudes but! What I am searching for is WHY my fileoutput filesize ends up being 5kb instead of 13,000+KB (The file that I am downloading from the internet) like I had it. I changed the output into a .txt instead of .exe to see what its downloading and it seems to only have a few lines in there, and not the whole "recvBufferTest"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nothing to do with Winsock, but rather to misuse of C++ strings.  (Mind you, I haven't gone through the rest of the code with a fine tooth-comb or anything, there may be additional issues as well.  But this is the one that stands out.)

When you say `recvBufferTest = recvBuffer` you are using the second form of the equals operator [as described here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/),

> Pointer to a **null-terminated** sequence of characters.  The sequence is copied as the new value for the string.

[emphasis mine.]

So for each block of data you obtain, you are setting `recvBufferTest` to contain the bytes up to but not including the first null character, and discarding the rest.  Since you are downloading an executable, zero bytes will be fairly common, so you are discarding most of the contents.

Conversely, if a block of data happened to contain no zero bytes, `recvBufferTest` will include whatever memory contents happen to follow `recvBuffer` in memory, up to but not including the first zero byte.  So if you were to download a text file, you'd likely find it was *longer* than expected.

Instead, you need to use a construction that allows you to specify the length of the data buffer.  For example, you could say something like

```
recvBufferTest.assign(recvBuffer, ReturnStuff);
```